# Source Code Control for Consultants?

Tags: version-control

Can anyone recommend a good Source Code control (SCC) that works for the mostly disconnected consultant? I'd prefer something that allows one to save into a local repository and then once connected 'syncs' to the server however I've never seen such a feature. Suggestions? [Windows solution is preferred that integrates with standard IDEs the SCCI API].

Answer (score 14):

Any distributed version control service is going to do that. Check out [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/) or [Git](http://git.or.cz/).

Comment: as a Git fan, it saddens me to say that Mercurial works better on Windows (I'm working on a project to remedy that, although there's no telling when I'll ever finish anything useful)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)).

It lets you commit things locally, and then resync back to another copy. Its very decentralized and it [appears to work in windows.](http://kylecordes.com/2008/03/22/git-windows-works/)

Answer (score 3):

Git may be a good alternative in this case.

From wikipedia: "Git gives each developer a local copy of the entire development history, and changes are copied from one such repository to another. These changes are imported as additional development branches, and can be merged in the same way as a locally developed branch. "

http://git.or.cz/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're working with Windows, I'd suggest syncing a local folder using TortoiseSVN on the client side (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to a VisualSVN Server-based repository on the server side (http://www.visualsvn.com/).

All available free.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a full up local repository, **it sounds like you might want to look at [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/)**.  I haven't used it other than a quick look-see, but it looks very interesting and powerful, and to the best of my knowledge provides a distributed source control process that replicates the repository allowing a disconnected user to still access things that they didn't "checkout" while connected.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you'll be better off with Mercurial. Especially if you're familiar with Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Git may be the closet thing to get to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Bazaar supports this [workflow](http://bazaar-vcs.org/Workflows?highlight=(workflows)#head-8b6348176ddc592bc64a124bd917e88569615def). It is also do able in git, but it's more intuitive in bzr, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry doesnt solve your want to have it merge to multiple repositories but SVN + TortoiseSVN on windows is a good combination. There are also Visual Studio plug ins for SVN if you use VS.

If you need a third party SVN provider i use [SVNRepository.com](http://www.svnrepository.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a distributed source code control.

Wikipedia has a good [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) of source code controls. I'd say pick the distributed source code control that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with most systems(cvs, svn, git, and so on). 
As for an application that will automatically sync when connected; I would not recommend this. It is better to commit intentionally. Depending on how you use a repository auto check in could break an active copy in your repository, or pass in code that hasn't been tested yet.

A decent client for subversion in windows is TortoiseSVN. http://tortoisesvn.net/

Answer (score 0):

If like GUIs, then check [plastic](http://www.plasticscm.com/xpproducts/xpcore/xpdistributed.aspx). It works both disconnected (well, actually distributed, using your own server at your laptop) and centralized